# Best way to check if all array values are in a range

Tags: php, arrays

How is best way to check if all array values are in range?

For example:

```
$range = range(10, 40);

$array1 = array(10, 20, 40); // OK 
$array2 = array(11, 22, 42, 30); // FALSE 
$array3 = array(50); // OK 
$array4 = array(10, 20, 30, 'a'); // FALSE 
$array5 = array("%", 20); // FALSE 
$array6 = array(10, 20, 40, 39, 40); // OK
```

So how can I check if array values are numbers (integer) and are in range?

I tried:

```
$tmp = 0;
foreach ($array1 as $a1) {
   if (!in_array($a1, $range) && is_int($a1)) {
      $tmp++;
   }
}

if ($tmp > 0) {
   echo "false";
} else {
echo "ok";
}
```

Maybe is better way? Maybe with `array_map()`?

Comment: so, what you have tried ??

Comment: The `min` function will give you the minimum value of all the arrays you throw at it. The `max` function will give you the maximum value of all the arrays that you throw at it. You can see if `min($a1, $a2, $a3)<10` to check the lower bound and do something similar for the upper bound.

Comment: 1 and 2 are not between 10 and 40 and neither is 5, etc... so your examples don't match the description.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. I updated my question.

Comment: don't you think $array3 = array(50); goes out of range 10 to 40, but you require output "OK" there, not much clear.

Comment: it might be better to not make the entire range and just pass the min and max values. if($min <= min($array) && max($array) <= $max)

Comment: @zofocu check the solution, I have posted, try o learn from that.

Answer (score 6):

```
    <?php
    $range      = range(10, 40);
    $array1     = array(10, 20, 40);
    $isInRange  = (min($array1)>=min($range) and max($array1)<=max($range)) ? "Yes" : "No";
    echo $isInRange;
    //prints 'Yes' when compared with array(10, 20, 40);
    //prints 'No' when compared with array(11, 22, 42, 30); as you have out range value 42 here
    ?>
```

A simplest way to check this is using `max` and `min` here, because you avoid validating for integers here. `max` selects the maximum value within the array, and `min` the least one.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do the job ?

It compare every value in the array with the range ($min and $max), and return "Not in range" if one of the value in the array is not between the specified range.

```
$min = 10;
$max = 40;


$array1 = array(10, 20, 40); // OK 


foreach ($array1 as $tmpArr){
    if (!($min<=$tmpArr && $tmpArr<=$max)){
        echo "Not in range";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_values_all_numbers($a, $min = PHP_INT_MIN, $max = PHP_INT_MAX){
  foreach($a as $v){
    if(is_int($v) && $v >= $min && $v <= $max){
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

var_dump(array_values_all_numbers(range(0, 100, 3))); // true
var_dump(array_values_all_numbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 'a'])); // false
var_dump(array_values_all_numbers([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 4)); // false
var_dump(array_values_all_numbers([1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 4)); // true
```

Or perhaps an alternative:

```
$myarray = array_filter(array_values($input), 'is_int');
foreach($myarray as $value){
  // loop over all array values that are numbers and skip the rest.
}
```

On a side-note; In terms of programming a *range* can mean a couple of things:

- Checking to see if a number is between two numbers.
- Range, looping *start* to *end* with an optional *step*.
- PHP function `range()`, returning an array from *start* to *end* with an optional *step*

It makes for a very confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun way:

```
var_dump(
    array_values($array1) == array_filter(array_values(array_intersect($range, $array1)), 'is_int')
);
```

- Compute the intersection between the range and array
- Remove non-integers
- Compare with the array
- Result is `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

just run it and learn fro here.

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(11, 20, 30); 
    $array2 = array(11, 22, 22, 30); 
    $array3 = array(20); 
    $array4 = array("a", 20, 30, 13); 
    $array5 = array(46, 20); 
    $array6 = array(52, 20, 31, 39, 30);

    $arr = array($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4, $array5, $array6);

    array_walk($arr, function($val){
        if(   min($val) > 10 && max($val) < 40){
            echo "<br/>matched for<br/>";
            print_r($val);
        } else {
            echo "<br/>not matched for<br />";
            print_r($val);
        }
    });
?>
```

There are a lot better way, you can try.

Output

```
matched for
Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 20 [2] => 30 ) 
matched for
Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 22 [2] => 22 [3] => 30 ) 
matched for
Array ( [0] => 20 ) 
not matched for
Array ( [0] => a [1] => 20 [2] => 30 [3] => 13 ) 
not matched for
Array ( [0] => 46 [1] => 20 ) 
not matched for
Array ( [0] => 52 [1] => 20 [2] => 31 [3] => 39 [4] => 30 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you have just a normal array not an associative array.

```
<?php

$a = array(1,2,3);
$b = array(2,3);
$c = array(2,3,4);

function all_in_range(array $needle, array $haystack) {
    return array_reduce(
        $needle,
        function($carry, $item) use ($haystack){
            return $carry?in_array($item,$haystack):false;
        },
        true
    );
}

var_dump(all_in_range($b, $a)); // check $b inside $a - true
var_dump(all_in_range($c, $a)); // check $c inside $a - false
```

results:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

=== or something like this ===

```
function all_in_range(array $needle, $min, $max) {
    return ( is_int($min) && is_int($max) ) ?
        array_reduce(
            $needle,
            function($carry, $item) use ($min, $max){
                // limits values are included
                return $carry?is_int($item)?($item>=$min && $item<=$max):false:false;
            },
            true
        ) : 'wrong limits';
}

var_dump(all_in_range($b, 1, 3)); // check $b inside range 1..3
var_dump(all_in_range($c, 1, 3)); // check $c inside range 1..3
```